# Поиск NS записи по всем DNS в resolv.conf

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dns

На клиентском компьютере в `/etc/resolv.conf` забиты 3 сервера:

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 192.168.1.2
nameserver 192.168.100.1
```

Все DNS сервера активны и работают.

**192.168.100.1** это DNS сервер для моей зоны `.int`, о которой первичные естественно ничего не знают.
Соответственно, если я с клиентского компьютера делаю поиск `server.int`, то поиск происходит по первичному DNS серверу и выдает:

```
Server:         192.168.1.1
Address:        192.168.1.1#53
** server can't find server.int: NXDOMAIN
```

Обращаясь непосредственно на `192.168.100.1` ответ отдается верный.

До недавнего времени я думал, что если мы производим поиск записи, то если не найдено на первом DNS сервере, то поиск производиться на последующих DNS серверах.

Отсюда вопрос - как сделать, что если запись не найдена на первичном сервере, поиск происходил на последующих из `/etc/resolv.conf`. Добавить нужные записи на первичные сервера нет возможности. Кеширующим и первичным делать тоже не хотелось бы. /etc/hosts не подходит. Поможет nsswitch?

Comment: На следующий DNS он полезет только если от первого вообще не получит ответ или получит ответ о ошибке самого сервера. В случае если сервер сообщает, что он искал и такого домена не существует, то на другие сервера запрос не уйдет. И боюсь единственным путем решения проблемы будет научить 192.168.1.1 брать нужную зону с 100.1 или поднять локально bind и в его конфиге описать зону с 100.1, а для остальных быть просто кеширующим с forward по тому списку серверов, что у вас сейчас в resolv.conf

Comment: @Mike, почему бы не скопировать это в ответ?

Comment: @Mike к сожалению, в итоге, пришлось ставить dnsmasq. Так что да, поддерживаю Александра, копируйте коммент в ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дополнительные записи resolv.conf (так же как и второй DNS в настройках сети windows и разных роутеров) используется только в случае, если первый DNS вообще не ответил или ответил о внутренней ошибке сервера. Т.е. только в том случае, когда первый DNS не смог дать точного ответа существует домен или нет.

В случае если сервер сообщает, что такого домена не существует, то на другие сервера запрос не уйдет. На этом все закончиться.

Единственным путем решения проблемы обеспечить что бы первый опрошенный DNS сервер выдал требуемую информацию. Для этого надо либо научить 192.168.1.1 брать нужную зону с 100.1 (явно описать в его конфиге в виде вторичной или кешируемой с указанием откуда брать). Или поднять локально bind (или другой удобный сервер), в котором явно описать с каких серверов брать дополнительные зоны (которые придется перечислить). Для всего остального сделать его стандартным кеширующим сервером DNS.